How to use an if statement with chars
I am trying to make a program where there are separate commands to output different ascii art. when I try to compile it gcc says warning: comparison between pointer and integer 10 |         if (cmd ==  'e'){ |                 ^~
Here is the code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main()
{

char  cmd;
while(true){
    scanf("\n%c", &cmd);
    if (cmd ==  'e'){
        int e = system("./e");   
 }
    else if (cmd ==  "train"){
        int tr = system("sl");
    }
}
return 0;
}


e is a separate binary i made that just prints some ascii art and sl is a command I have installed on my system.
I tried making the cmd variable a pointer and that didn't work so I changed it back. It's supposed to print do these things when they are called upon.

char on its own is a single character, not a string - and you also have to use strcmp

"train" is not a char. It is a string literal. Make cmd a big enough array of char to handle your input including a null terminator, read a string into it, and use strcmp.

while(true){ scanf("\n%c", &cmd); is an anti-pattern.  If you do not read anything from the input stream, you almost certainly want to terminate the loop.   Use the standard idiom while(1 == scanf(...))

The error should be happening on the if (cmd == "train") line, not if (cmd == 'e'). So either you copied the error wrong or it came from a different version of the code.

Welcome so SO. Apart from being the wrong way to compare strings, how would cmd ever hold such a string? It is a single char and you only read exactly one character via scanf.
